# Import data from oracle into hive using sqoop - cannot use --hive-partition-key

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have a simple table:

```
create table osoba(id number, imie varchar2(100), nazwisko varchar2(100), wiek integer);
insert into osoba values(1, 'pawel','kowalski',36);
insert into osoba values(2, 'john','smith',55);
insert into osoba values(3, 'paul','psmithski',44);
insert into osoba values(4, 'jakub','kowalski',70);
insert into osoba values(5, 'scott','tiger',70);

commit;
```

that i want to import into Hive using sqoop. I want to have partitioned table  in Hive. This is my sqoop command:

```
-bash-4.1$ sqoop import -Dmapred.job.queue.name=pr  --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/oracle_database" \
--username "user" --password "password" --table osoba --hive-import \
--hive-table pk.pk_osoba --delete-target-dir --hive-overwrite \
--hive-partition-key nazwisko
```

And I get an error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10035]: Column repeated in partitioning columns
```

Can anyone suggest how --hive-partition-key parameter should be used?
Sqoop command without --hive-partition-key parameter works fine and creates table pk.pk_osoba in Hive.

Regards

Pawel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In columns option provide all those columns name which you want to import except the partition column. We don't specify the partition column in --columns option as it get automatically added.

Below is the example:
I am importing DEMO2 table with columns ID,NAME, COUNTRY. I have not specified COUNTRY column name in --columns options as it is my partition column name.

```
 $SQOOP_HOME/bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.41.67:1521/orcl --username orcluser1 --password impetus --hive-import --table DEMO2 --hive-table "DEMO2" --columns ID,NAME --hive-partition-key 'COUNTRY' --hive-partition-value 'INDIA' --m 1 --verbose --delete-target-dir --target-dir /tmp/13/DEMO2
```

Comment: I think it is to import only India data. what if I want to import all data into hive partition table. (dynamic partitioning is enabled in hive)?